# Is there some way to load dense graph format (g6) from Nauty GENG into GraphViz?

Tags: graph, graphviz

I've generated a graph with Nauty geng, now I need to use Graphviz.

How can I go from G6 to DOT?

PS: I'm very newbie with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brendan has a [showg utility](https://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/data/formats.html) which translates them into easier to read formats.

Comment: If you hack the function that prints the -e option it's pretty easy to have it spit graphviz instead.